# What do you call an object in an operad that is not the composition of other objects?

Tags: category-theory, operads

I have an operad with object sets $P(n)$. For most $n$, there exists at least one object $x\in P(n)$ such that for all sets of other objects and all compositions thereof, $x$ is not equal to that composition.

Is there a convention for what to call $x$? An atom? An atomic object?

Comment: Since composition is a type of multiplication, you could ask the same question for multiplication and get an answer.

Comment: @Alephnull thanks--I suppose the answer would be "prime" in the context of the integers, but is this term used in the context of operads?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe $x$ would typically be called "indecomposable", like in algebras.

Note that in order to define correctly what indecomposable means, you need to realize that you can always write $x = \operatorname{id}(x) = x(\operatorname{id},\dots,\operatorname{id})$ where $1$ is the identity of your operad. So you need to discard such trivial compositions.

If you have an operad of sets this works fine, in more general settings you probably need to consider an augmented operad (i.e. an operad equipped with a map $\varepsilon : P(1) \to I$ where $I$ is the unit of your monoidal category, satisfying $\varepsilon \eta = \operatorname{id}_I$ where $\eta : I \to P(1)$ represents the unit). Then an indecomposable is something that isn't in the image of $\bar{P} \circ_{(1)} \bar{P} \to P$, where $\bar{P}$ is the augmentation ideal.

Comment: Hi Najib, thanks for your reply. Just to be sure, it sounds like I ought to explicitly define indecomposable in my writing, right? That is, it isn't in common-enough usage to be tossed around without a careful definition. (This is for a combinatorics/algebraic topology audience)

Comment: @JosephSlote I think it'd be OK to not define it, but then it doesn't cost much to define it...